# Regex Need To Match Number To 2 decimal places but 1 digits allowed with zero

Tags: java

I need some regex that will match only numbers that are decimal to two places.

For example:

200.00-match

200.11-match

200.121-no match

200.520-match

200.101-no match

200.000-match

200.0001-no match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression works for your case

```
^[0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]0*$
```

[Your test data here](https://regex101.com/r/TbPR5b/1)